# Splitting characters from a text file in Python

Tags: python, string, list

So I am importing a txt with say

```
abc
dfg
fgh
```

contained in the txt file. Though currently I am getting it in the form of

```
[[abc],[dgf],[fgh],]
```

When im trying to get

```
[['a','b','c'],['d','g','f'],['f','g','h']]
```

My currently code is

```
f = open(filename, 'rU')
result = [line.list(',') for line in f.readlines()]
```

How can I change this to get it to seperate each character in the lists?

Comment: Did your code work as given?  A string object has no `list` attribute.

Comment: Yes, it would return what i said in the 2nd code area.

Comment: You sure?  When I copy and paste your code exactly, I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'list'`.  It comes from `line.list(',')`.  A `str` has no `.list()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just `list(line.rstrip())`, `list()` can convert a string to list of single characters:

```
with open('filname') as f:
    result = [list(line.rstrip()) for line in f]
```

And don't use `file.readlines`, you can iterate over the file object itself.

**Demo:**

```
>>> list("foobar")
['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```

Comment: Ohh that makes so much more sense! Thankyou!

Comment: @user2330621 Note that there's no need to convert those strings to lists unless you're trying to mutate them, as strings are iterable too.